# Accessing the output of the Network Interface Card

Tags: networking, network-interface, system-calls, wlan

I am working on a project in which I need to interface directly with the WLAN Network Interface card, i.e., using the drivers of course. It is lot like wireshark. Also, I want to send some custom built frames using the NIC. I mean, I want the output of the physical layer directly, i.e., a bunch of bits. Is there any system call in Linux that can help?

Thank you!!

Edit: My question: How can I do the things mentioned above? A small example will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The "physical layer" used for WLAN is more complicated than you think, it's actually several layers.

Out of the box, without hacking and modifying the firmware of a specific card, the lowest you can get is to capture packets with 802.11 headers, by enabling "monitor mode" in that driver (which usually will give you a second WLAN interface).

Wireshark can capture and display those headers. See e.g. [here](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN) for details, see `man iw` how to enable monitor mode, use `iw phy` to see if your hardware supports monitor mode.

See `aircrack-ng` for other tools you can use for capture and injection of packets on that level.